# Sql server memory increase while monitoring in task manager

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2012

I have an issue in sql server , my project is developed with entity framework and wcf services . while monitoring in task manager the memory increases, when the limit exceeds my application hangs. this is big issue . when i restart services of sql server instance in services , its memory decreases to low and works fine.

i'm daily restarting services.this is not a good solution for it. As it is going to increase in feature more than large volume as expected .

If any wrong pls correct me .pls give me a better solution for this asap.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to understand how sql server manages memory. What is happening is normal, and the problem is not what you think it is....

Comment: sorry but i dont know sql server 2012 much about it, when i restarted services application works fine. i have monitored in profiler also memory for linq query also memory is more...can u give me idea how to check and resolve this issue----- @MitchWheat

Comment: You can limit Sql server memory usage.

Comment: Yeah i can do but day to day sql server size is going to be increased.how the memory increase also dont know.

Answer (score 1):

The issue sometimes happens because of opening multiple connection without properly closing it.So all connection is remain open in sql server.

Just check the .Open() and Close() for your connection in your project code.

Comment: there is no above functions in  my project it is handled everything in the context it self